# Access bluetooth RFCOMM through android terminal

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, serial-port, rfcomm

I would like to access to RFCOMM to set up a bluetooth virtual serial port on my Android device using the terminal.
I do have root permissions on my android device. 
When I type "rfcomm" in the terminal, I receive a message saying "rfcomm: not found". It seems I do not have an application rfcomm in my system. Where do I find that? Did I miss any other command? Unfortunately I am not used to work with linux frameworks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to bluetooth as well, but I may be able to help you (note caveats at bottom of this answer)..
I assume you're trying to run rfcomm on an embedded linux system right..
Assuming yes...
You need to make sure you have bluez tools installed (google for info on that).
Then run: "rfkill unblock bluetooth".
Then, I wrote my own rfcomm server based on this... https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html

With that running on my embedded linux machine I am able to run the blueterm app and establish a basic terminal connection between my android phone and my embedded system.

CAVEATS:
Bluetooth development is new to me, and this solution just works when using BlueTerm (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.pymasde.blueterm&hl=en).  I've noticed that it doesn't work with other similar bluetooth terminal apps for some reason (don't know why, if someone knows please post), and as of Android 6.0.1 on my Samsung S6 (just installed the other day), the BlueTerm app doesn't even work for me.  I'm investigating this now and will post results if I find any.

The rfcomm_srvr.c code posted at the site above is clearly dated (but it works).
If someone else reads this and knows a better (more modern, more efficient) way to do this (without writing an Android app), I'd like to hear about it too.

**UPDATE:** Ok, so it appears that BlueTerm has some kind of user interface problem with my phone as of the 6.0.1 upgrade.  I transitioned over to BlueTerm2 (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.fusionimage.blueterm2) and things work fine.  This means you can use that rfcomm_srvr.c code as a base for a useful terminal interface.